# Applications of étale cohomology

Tags: etale-cohomology, reference-request

It is well-known that étale cohomology is used in the proof of Weil conjectures and that SGA 4.5 is devoted to it. Also it seems(from a brief perusal of Milne's notes) that it is a kind of Galois Cohomology/Kummer theory for arbitrary algebraic varieties.

However I have heard a lot of people praising it, and this leads me to suspect that it must have applications beyond proving the Weil conjectures. I would be grateful if some of these can be given. I am sorry if this is a stupid question. The wikipedia page, Milne's article, etc., did not give any extra applications and so I hope asking people is more sensible. Please provide references also if available.

Comment: Let me ask a related question. Do you know any applications of cohomology?? Any cohomology theory at all? Isn't it nice when the objects we're studying can be studied using cohomology, because cohomology linearises everything and turns stuff abelian, it's tangent spaces and things like that but it's oh so general. And now, if the things I happen to like studying are algebraic varieties, isn't it great that there's a cohomology theory! I now have access to all the wonderful linearisation tricks that it offers. Isn't that reason enough?

Comment: @Buzzard. But we already have sheaf cohomology for that. Even after all the other cohomology theories, it just seems the most-used cohomology theory. It just seems impossible that an algebraic geometer can do without sheaf cohomology. I am asking, what is the extra special thing with etale cohomology, in addition to the application to Weil conjectures, etc.. 

Comment: @Regenbogen Sheaf cohomology for varieties in char p give vector spaces in char p. If you want to study, say, algebraic cycles, you need a characteristic zero cohomology. It's not just for the Weil conjectures, it's for everything.

Comment: Fantastic answers to the same question here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/6070/etale-cohomology-why-study-it

Comment: Then why is it the case that sheaf cohomology is still the most widely used theory?

Comment: @Hunter. Oh I am sorry, I didn't know that a very similar question was already asked. I however hope this won't be closed, though.

Comment: "Why is it the case ... ?" Because of the particular aspects of geometry that you have studied.  If you studied other aspects of algebraic geometry over the complex numbers, you would see many applications of singular cohomology.  If you studied arithmetic geometry, you would see many application of etale cohomology (which plays the same role, roughly,
as singular cohomology does in the complex setting).

Comment: @Regenbogen: I'm not so sure that sheaf cohomology really is "the cohomology" of an algebraic variety. If I gave you a complex torus T and asked you what dimension its H^1 should be, surely you would answer "2". But H^1(T,O) is not 2-dimensional, it's H^1(T,C) that's 2-dimensional. The problem is how to do H^1(T,C) if T is now an elliptic curve over a more general base (e.g. Q, or Z/pZ). Etale cohomology solves that problem, and that problem is absolutely fundamental to the theory. Even if the Weil conjectures had been solved using other methods, etale cohomology would still have been born.

Comment: @Emerton. I see the merit of your position; but I am not yet fully moved. Even with the advent of "motives", supposedly the best of all, so many papers in algebraic geometry are full of sheaf cohomology, and I was told, "if you are interested in algebraic geometry, you just have to learn sheaf cohomology; there is no other way". For instance, for moduli spaces, the Quot or Picard schemes, sheaf cohomology paves the way.

Comment: @Buzzard. If you mean etale cohomology as a Weil cohomology theory, then wikipedia has the examples of crystalline cohomology, algebraic de Rham cohomology, motives, etc.(though I do not understand these).

Comment: Regenbogen- etale cohomology IS sheaf cohomology.  Most often people use that name to refer to the cohomology of the constant sheaf (an analogue of topological cohomology, which is the cohomology of the constant sheaf in a usual topology), but the point of the etale cohomology is this: while taking cohomology in the Zariski topology works with coherent sheaves, for some other types of sheaves, it gives the wrong answer, so you need to take a different sort of topology on an algebraic variety, the etale topology (which isn't really a topology, but a generalization of one).

Comment: @Regenborgen: OK, how about this for an answer. For smooth manifolds you have sheaf cohomology, and you have singular cohomology, and both have their uses. For algebraic varieties you still have sheaf cohomology, but where is your singular cohomology? The answer is that it wasn't there for a long time, and then it was there, in the form of etale cohomology. 

Comment: @Ben Webster, @Kevin Buzzard. Thanks for your answers. It helped me appreciate etale cohomology conceptually. @Ben: Are you saying that with constant coefficients, etale cohomology is a generalization of sheaf cohomology, replacing the Zariski site with the etale site? @Buzzard. Yes, now I conceptually understand it more. But still some explicit applications will be nice, to strengthen the convictions.

Comment: @Regenbogen: the very _definition_ of etale cohomology, with coefficients in Z/p^n, is the cohomology of the constant sheaf Z/p^n on the etale site. And then you take the projective limit over n to get the etale cohomology with coefficients in Z_p. And then you prove a theorem that if your variety is e.g. smooth projective over C, with associated complex manifold M, the etale coh with coefficients in Z_p coincides with the singular coh of M with coefficients in Z_p. And then you know you're onto something.

Answer (score 9):

One of the most important applications of etale cohomology is to Deligne-Lusztig theory, and the large subsequent body of work approaching the representation of finite groups of Lie type using $\ell$-adic cohomology.  For me, this is the most important application beyond the Weil conjectures.

In addition to the original paper of Deligne and Lusztig "Representations of reductive groups over finite fields" in Ann. of Math 1976, you might be interested in the book "Weil Conjectures, Perverse Sheaves and l'adic Fourier Transform", by Weissauer and Kiehl.

Answer (score 9):

If $X$ is a variety over $k$, the $\ell$-adic cohomology groups $H^i(X\otimes_k \overline{k},\mathbb{Q}_\ell)$ carry an action of $Gal(\overline{k}/k)$. This makes etale cohomology a very efficient (and the only?) tool to produce interesting Galois representations.

A typical example is $H^1(E_{\overline{Q}},Q_\ell)$ for an elliptic curve $E$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. This is dual to $(\varprojlim E[\ell^n]) \otimes_{Z_\ell} Q_\ell$ where $E[\ell^n] \subset E(\overline{\mathbb{Q}})$ is the set of $\ell^n$-torsion points of the curve. The action of $Gal(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q})$ on $H^1(E_{\overline{\mathbb{Q}}},\mathbb{Q}_\ell)$ corresponds to its action on $E(\overline{Q})$. So for each elliptic curve over $\mathbb{Q}$, one gets a 2 dimensional representation of $Gal(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q})$ (actually one for each $\ell$).
These are central objects in the arithmetic of elliptic curves.

The proof of the Langlands correspondance for $GL_n$ by Drinfeld and Lafforgue uses the same principle. To associate a Galois representation to an automorphic representation they realize it as some $\ell$-adic cohomology group of a space.

Comment: My only nitpick with this answer: It's not quite accurate to say that representations of Gal(Q) are central to the arithmetic of elliptic curves; I'd say that they're right near the center of number theory!

Answer (score 0):

It can be used to give a short proof of the weak Mordell-Weil theorem, see my answer in [Proofs of Mordell-Weil theorem](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/72288/proofs-of-mordell-weil-theorem).

Another application: Proving the ($p'$-part of the) conjecture of Birch and Swinnerton-Dyer for Abelian schemes over $1$- or higher dimensional bases over finite fields under the assumption that the algebraic rank equals the analytic rank or one $\ell$-primary subgroup of the Tate-Shafarevich group is finite.