# Elementary proof of Mordell's theorem

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

My question concerns a comment in Silverman-Tate's book "Rational Points on Elliptic Curves" (second printing). On page 76 they begin their proof of 'lemma 4' to the proof of Mordell's theorem, which is to say that the subgroup $2C(\mathbb{Q})$ in $C(\mathbb{Q})$, the group of rational points for some elliptic curve $E/\mathbb{Q}$, has finite index. They make the comment

"Unfortunately, we do not know how to prove Lemma 4 for all cubic curves without using some algebraic number theory, and we want to stick to the rational numbers. So we are going to make the additional assumption that the polynomial $f(x)$ has at least one rational root, which amounts to saying that the curve has at least one rational point of order two. The same method of proof works in general if you take a root of the equation $f(x) = 0$ and work in the field generated by that root over the rationals. But ultimately we would need to know some basic facts about the unit group and the ideal class group of the field, topics which we prefer to avoid."

My question is has this situation been improved? Can Mordell's theorem be proved in generality without resorting to algebraic number theory?

Comment: Could you give some motivation? For you, what would qualify as not resorting to algebraic number theory?

Comment: There may be proofs of Mordell's theorem that don't use any algebraic number theory (perhaps Mordell's original proof doesn't), but I doubt whether you would want to read them. You could try looking in Mordell's book or at the article Cassels, J. W. S., Mordell's finite basis theorem revisited. Math. Proc. Cambridge Philos. Soc. 100 (1986), no. 1, 31–41. 

Comment: You might want to have a look at the proofs of Mordell-Weil listed in the answers to this questions : http://mathoverflow.net/questions/72288/proofs-of-mordell-weil-theorem.  I would especially recommend the one in Cassels's *Lectures on Elliptic Curves*.

Comment: Edited only to correct a distracting typo "we want to sick 
to the rational numbers": stick, not sick.

Comment: The ultimate reason for Mordell's result to work must have something to do with the arithmetic of $\mathbb{Q}$ or number fields. For instance, elliptic curves over $\mathbb{C}$ has uncountably many $\mathbb{C}$-points and so cannot finitely generated. It would be interesting to have an infinite extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ for which Mordell's result holds.

Comment: @anon Mordell's original proof did use finiteness of class number.

Answer (score 10):

Not sure if this answers your question, but here's a thought.

The known proofs that $E(K)/mE(K)$ is finite are non-effective because they embed $E(K)/mE(K)$ into a larger group that is shown to be finite. Let's call that larger group $S^{(m)}$. The proof that $S^{(m)}$ is finite is effective, and indeed it yields a very nice upper bound for the order of $S^{(m)}$. However, as far as I know, this bound always involves (at least) the $m$-part of the class number of $K(P)$, where $P$ is an $m$-torsion point of $E$. So the proof requires algebraic number theory in the sense that one needs to know that the class group (or at least the $m$ part) of some extension field of $K$ is finite, unless there is a rational $m$ torsion point. So proofs along these lines would seem to require algebraic number theory and ideal class groups, either explicitly or disguised in some way.

Comment: I have read a recent paper by Watkins that suggests that elliptic curves whose group of rational points has torsion are 'rare'. If the set of torsion points is the reason why algebraic number theory is involved, then is it possible to be able to prove Mordell's theorem for 'most' curves without using any information about ideal class groups?

Comment: Joe's answer says that on the contrary it is when you have a torsion point defined over $\mathbf{Q}$ that you *don't* need to worry about things like ideal class groups.

Answer (score 9):

In the meantime I have been able to consult Cassels's *Lectures on Elliptic Curves*. He proves Mordell's theorem in Chapter 15, which has these two interesting footnotes :

> ${}^{16}$ This is the only place where
> the use of algebraic number theory is
> unavoidable.  If she does not know the
> theory, the reader should take it on
> trust that it is very like the
> rational case.  But see next footnote.
>
> ${}^{17}$ This line of argument proves
> the finiteness of
> $\mathfrak{G}/2\mathfrak{G}$ without
> algebraic number theory at the expense
> of a fairly substantial study of
> binary quartic forms.

The main text says at this point:

> In fact this is what Birch and
> Swinnerton-Dyer did in their historic
> computations [Notes on elliptic
> curves. I, II. *J. reine angew. Math.*
> [**212** (1963), 7--25](http://eudml.org/doc/150565), [**218**
> (1965), 79--108](http://eudml.org/doc/150676)].

It must be added that it is this approach via binary quartic forms which has made the recent spectacular advances by Arul Shankar and Manjul Bhargava possible; see [arXiv:1006.1002](http://arxiv.org/abs/1006.1002).